# uploading and accessing images into asp .net api folder using angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I have angular project as my client side and .Net 6 web api project as my backend. I am still new to both technologies. I am creating a website and there is a functionality that I am trying to add and haven't been successful so far. I want to upload images into a .Net web api project images folder using angular. I also want to later access those images from angular project. I want to store the path of the image files in the database. I have tried to check for the code on the internet without success. Your assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Will vote to close - please read https://stackoverflow.com/tour https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

First, submit your's files from frontend with `FormData`

```
postWithFile(url: string, obj: any, files: File[]) {
  let cloneHeader: any = {};
  let options: any = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders(cloneHeader),
    observe: 'response',
    responseType: 'json'
  };
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  if (typeof obj == 'object') { // obj is external submit data
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(obj));
  } else {
    formData.append('data', obj);
  }
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    files.forEach((ds, index) => {
      formData.append('file_' + index, ds, ds.name);
    });
  }
  return this._http
    .post(this.host + url, formData, options)
    .pipe(map((res: any) => {
      return res.body;
    }));
}
```

And backend handle request with `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files`, save images to server and store path of images in database

```
[HttpPost]
public ResponseMessage<bool?> UploadImages()
{
    var response = new ResponseMessage<bool?>();
    try
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        ExternalDataModel model = MessageConvert.DeserializeObject<ExternalDataModel>(HttpContext.Current.Request["data"]); // obj in frontend
        //
        List<string> listImages = new List<string>();
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string buildPath = $"{string.Format("{0:00}", now.Year)}\\{string.Format("{0:00}", now.Month)}\\{string.Format("{0:00}", now.Day)}"; // change by your's folder path
        foreach (string file in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files)
        {
            var fileContent = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[file];
            int fileLength = fileContent.ContentLength;
            if (fileContent != null && fileLength > 0)
            {
                var stream = fileContent.InputStream;
                byte[] imgByteArray;
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    imgByteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
                string fileName = $"format_file_name_if_need_{fileContent.FileName}";
                string RelativeFolder = $"{buildPath}";
                string AbsoluteFolder = Path.Combine("FOLDER_IN_SERVER_FULL_PATH", RelativeFolder);
                if (!Directory.Exists(AbsoluteFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(AbsoluteFolder);
                }
                string pathSave = Path.Combine(RelativeFolder, fileName);
                FileHelper.SaveFileFromBinaryArray(pathSave, imgByteArray);
                listImages.Add(pathSave);
            }
        }
        // model.listImages = listImages; // assign to model to save to DB
        //
        // var data = _bus.uploadImage(model);
        // if (data)
        // {
        //     response.Data = true;
        //     response.MessageCode = MessageCodes.UpdateSuccessfully;
        // }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.MessageCode = ex.Message;
    }
    return response;
}
```